# GPU crashes randomly

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, gpu, visual-artifacts

This week my gpu crashes randomly, at first i had PopOS and it started crashing, then i moved to Manjaro - crash, now I am with Ubuntu and it is still the same - crash.One thing I noticed about crash is my vega 56 has power states indicators, each one represnts each state and when I am playing League Of Legends for example it always stays at the first state, then it crashes and my gpu power state indicators shows that gpu enters the 8th power state. When my gpu crashed (also I was having artifacts like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/89mVH.jpg) while I was using PopOS (I was using KDE plasma) this is what i found in logs:

```
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052278] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:6 pasid:32777, for process plasmashell pid 2291 thread plasmashel:cs0 pid 2641)
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052282] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x00000001059cb000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052283] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00401031
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052284] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052285] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052286] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052287] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052288] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052289] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052295] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:6 pasid:32777, for process plasmashell pid 2291 thread plasmashel:cs0 pid 2641)
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052296] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x00000001059d1000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052297] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052298] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052299] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052300] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052301] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052302] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052303] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052308] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:6 pasid:32777, for process plasmashell pid 2291 thread plasmashel:cs0 pid 2641)
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052309] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x00000001059c2000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052310] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052311] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052312] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052312] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052313] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052314] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052315] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052320] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:6 pasid:32777, for process plasmashell pid 2291 thread plasmashel:cs0 pid 2641)
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052321] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x00000001059c0000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052322] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052323] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052328] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052329] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052330] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052331] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052332] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052338] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:6 pasid:32777, for process plasmashell pid 2291 thread plasmashel:cs0 pid 2641)
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052339] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x00000001059c1000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052340] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00601031
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052340] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052341] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052342] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052343] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052344] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052345] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052351] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:6 pasid:32777, for process plasmashell pid 2291 thread plasmashel:cs0 pid 2641)
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052352] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x00000001059cc000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052353] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052354] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052355] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052356] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052357] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052357] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052358] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052376] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:6 pasid:32777, for process plasmashell pid 2291 thread plasmashel:cs0 pid 2641)
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052377] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x00000001059c5000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052379] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00601031
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052380] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052381] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052382] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052384] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052385] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:23 pop-os kernel: [11220.052386] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442256] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442259] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f7c000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442260] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00601031
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442261] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442262] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442263] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442264] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442265] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442266] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442273] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442274] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f8b000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442275] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442276] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442277] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442283] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442283] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442284] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442285] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442291] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442292] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f89000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442293] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00101031
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442294] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442295] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442296] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442297] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442298] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442299] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442304] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442308] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f68000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442309] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442310] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442311] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442312] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442313] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442314] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442314] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442320] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442321] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f3e000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442322] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00101031
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442323] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442324] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442325] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442326] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442326] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442327] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442332] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442334] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116faa000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442334] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442335] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442336] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442337] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442338] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442339] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442340] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442345] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442346] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f81000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442347] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442348] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442349] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442353] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442354] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442355] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442355] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442361] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442362] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f74000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442363] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00101031
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442364] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442365] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442366] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442366] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442367] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442368] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442373] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442374] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f79000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442375] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00000000
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442376] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442377] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442378] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442379] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442380] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442381] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442388] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32788, for process chromium pid 9297 thread chromium:cs0 pid 9303)
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442389] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000000116f2a000 from client 27
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442390] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00101031
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442391] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442392] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442393] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442394] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442395] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Jan 11 11:53:30 pop-os kernel: [11226.442396] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:       RW: 0x0
```

Then I installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS (I am using Cinnamon) and today is the first time I get crash. So I decided to look at the logs, this is the last logs before crash:

```
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635550] kauditd_printk_skb: 187 callbacks suppressed
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635552] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397772): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635584] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397773): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635615] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397774): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635644] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397775): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635673] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397776): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635702] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397777): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635731] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397778): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635760] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397779): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635789] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397780): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:00:51 mk kernel: [24796.635818] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478051.000:397781): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.635618] kauditd_printk_skb: 156 callbacks suppressed
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.635619] audit: type=1400 audit(1610478061.000:397938): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=21518 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636813] audit: audit_backlog=65 > audit_backlog_limit=64
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636814] audit: audit_lost=10834 audit_rate_limit=0 audit_backlog_limit=64
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636815] audit: backlog limit exceeded
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636833] audit: audit_backlog=65 > audit_backlog_limit=64
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636834] audit: audit_lost=10835 audit_rate_limit=0 audit_backlog_limit=64
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636834] audit: backlog limit exceeded
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636854] audit: audit_backlog=65 > audit_backlog_limit=64
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636855] audit: audit_lost=10836 audit_rate_limit=0 audit_backlog_limit=64
Jan 12 21:01:01 mk kernel: [24806.636855] audit: backlog limit exceeded
```

This is linux and pc specifications:

```
vega@mk:~$ neofetch 
vega@mk 

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic 
Uptime: 1 hour, 1 min 
Packages: 2612 (dpkg), 8 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 2560x1440 
DE: Cinnamon 
WM: Mutter (Muffin) 
WM Theme: Adapta-Nokto (Adapta-Nokto) 
Theme: Adapta-Nokto [GTK2/3] 
Icons: LoginIcons [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel i5-3450 (4) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX Vega 56/64 
Memory: 6198MiB / 15961MiB
```

Also I did a quick stress test and It passed completely normal.

```
vega@mk:~$ glmark2 
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     X.Org
    GL_RENDERER:   Radeon RX Vega (VEGA10, DRM 3.38.0, 5.8.0-36-generic, LLVM 11.0.0)
    GL_VERSION:    4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.2.6
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false:
 FPS: 4136 FrameTime: 0.242 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 5782 FrameTime: 0.173 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 5805 FrameTime: 0.172 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 5880 FrameTime: 0.170 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 5955 FrameTime: 0.168 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud: FPS: 5993 FrameTime: 0.167 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf: FPS: 6120 FrameTime: 0.163 ms
[shading] shading=phong: FPS: 5884 FrameTime: 0.170 ms
[shading] shading=cel: FPS: 5929 FrameTime: 0.169 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly: FPS: 6105 FrameTime: 0.164 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals: FPS: 5822 FrameTime: 0.172 ms
[bump] bump-render=height: FPS: 5890 FrameTime: 0.170 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;: FPS: 5967 FrameTime: 0.168 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;: FPS: 6346 FrameTime: 0.158 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false: FPS: 5397 FrameTime: 0.185 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4: FPS: 3999 FrameTime: 0.250 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4: FPS: 3995 FrameTime: 0.250 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 715 FrameTime: 1.399 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata: FPS: 904 FrameTime: 1.106 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=true:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map: FPS: 772 FrameTime: 1.295 ms
[ideas] speed=duration: FPS: 2640 FrameTime: 0.379 ms
[jellyfish] <default>: FPS: 5266 FrameTime: 0.190 ms
[terrain] <default>: FPS: 1935 FrameTime: 0.517 ms
[shadow] <default>: FPS: 4722 FrameTime: 0.212 ms
[refract] <default>: FPS: 4051 FrameTime: 0.247 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 6069 FrameTime: 0.165 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=0: FPS: 5996 FrameTime: 0.167 ms
[conditionals] fragment-steps=0:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 6211 FrameTime: 0.161 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=low:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 6077 FrameTime: 0.165 ms
[function] fragment-complexity=medium:fragment-steps=5: FPS: 6268 FrameTime: 0.160 ms
[loop] fragment-loop=false:fragment-steps=5:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 6119 FrameTime: 0.163 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=false:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 6091 FrameTime: 0.164 ms
[loop] fragment-steps=5:fragment-uniform=true:vertex-steps=5: FPS: 6074 FrameTime: 0.165 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 4997 
=======================================================
```

Does anyone know why it is happening and how do I fix it? Big Thanks!